# Confusion while evaluating conditions with more than one logical NOT operator

Tags: c++, c

I'm confused when code includes more than one NOT operator like:

```
if (!x != !0)
  ;
```

or similar. I can read it as: if NOT x is NOT equal to NOT zero,
but in my mind I'm totally confused about what it actually means.

Do you have any advice regarding this? I.e. how to understand such code, where to start reading or etc.

Another example:

```
if(!x == !1)
```

Comment: Pick a language you are actually using. You cannot compile both C and C++ in the same compilation unit. Then study the operator precedence table of the language you chose.

Comment: Do note that even the behaviour of `!0` is not identical in C and C++

Comment: @AnttiHaapala You would do people a favor if you explained what you meant rather than tossing off cryptic comments like that.  (I consider myself an expert, but I don't know what you mean, and I'd be hard-pressed to look it up.)

Comment: @SteveSummit it is not cryptic, it just shows that there is no such thing as **C/C++**. And I still see that the tags do not take stances here about which one this is supposed to be. I don't know what *other* differences there are but the value of boolean operators in C++ is of type `bool` and `int` in C.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) if you are not sure. For instance

```
x | 0 | x!=0 | !x | !0 | !x != !0
0 | 0 |  0   |  1 |  1 |    0
1 | 0 |  1   |  0 |  1 |    1
```

If have problems with many && and ||, use [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: Your x!=0 column seems to be inverted.

Answer (score 1):

to make things simpler, evaluate the `operator!` first then read L->R.

Things to remember:

```
!0 = 1 // true
!1 = 0 // false
```

so your condition can be simplified to:

```
if (!x != true)  // !0
if (!x == false) // !1
```

Now, any *non-zero* value when inverted will be `zero`.

```
int x = 10;
!x // zero
```

*Zero* when inverted is `true`.

```
int x = 0;
!x // one
```

In C or C++, `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the question is about C, and therefore I will give the answer in C.

You need to know the precedence rules - the `!` binds stronger than the `!=`. Therefore the expression can be clarified using parentheses as `(!x) != (!0)`. Now, the next thing is to know what `!` will do - the result will be `0` if the operand is *non-zero*, `1` if it is zero. Therefore, `!0` can be constant-folded to `1`.

Now we have `(!x) != 1`. Since the `!x` is 1 **iff** `x` is zero, the result of this entire expression will be 1 iff `x` is non-zero, 0 otherwise.

We can therefore reduce this expression into the more idiomatic double-negation: `!!x`. However, the `if` clause in itself tests whether the expression is non-zero, therefore the entire `if` statement can be changed to `if (x) ;` (and since the expression does guard only a null-statement, it can be elided altogether)

Answer (score 0):

I got troubled as well with simalar syntax when I started developing on PowerBuilder, then I realized I just need to imagine it as a nested if checking false.
For example !x become if(x)=false so it makes more clear that is true when x is false or zero. 
In C 0 is false, whatever is not zero is true.

In the same logic !1 is always false and !0 is always true, despite I cannot see the reason to type it in this confusing way, maybe the code you are looking at is coming out from a sort of automatic generator / converter.

Answer (score 0):

First take a look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). You will see that [logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical) like `!` take precedence over [relational operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) like `!=`.

Secondly, what is `!0` - this suspiciously sounds like there is an implicit conversion from `int` to `bool` there - otherwise `!0` would make no sense at all.

In your example, you need to evaluate the logical operators first (i.e. `!x` and `!0`), then check if they are not equal `!=`. That said, this kind of code is **really bad** as it is **really hard to read** - avoid writing code like this, if possible (and consider refactoring it - while covered by unit tests - if you encounter it in "the wild")

Answer (score 0):

This kind of code is designed to trick you. Your brain have difficulty to process double-negation or triple negation (and you are not the only one).

You need to know what are the priority rules, and apply it:

`(!x == !1)` is equal to `((!x) == (!1))`

If you see this kind of code during a code review, you should definitely highlight it, and ask for an update.

Please note that in C++ you can also use `not` instead of `!`. It can makes things easier to understand:

`(!x == !1)` is equal to `((not x) == (not 1))`

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++, a value of zero is considered "false", and a nonzero value is considered "true".  But it can occasionally be confusing, and occasionally causes minor problems, that two different values can both be considered true even though they're, well, different.

For example, suppose you had a function `is_rich()` that told you whether a person was rich or not.  And suppose you wrote code like this:

```
int harry_is_rich = is_rich("Harry");
int sally_is_rich = is_rich("Sally");
```

Now the variable `harry_is_rich` is zero or nonzero according to whether Harry is poor or rich, and `sally_is_rich` is zero or nonzero according to whether Sally is poor or rich.

Now suppose you're interested in knowing whether Harry and Sally are both rich, or both poor.  Your first thought might be

```
if(harry_is_rich == sally_is_rich)
```

But wait.  Since any nonzero value is considered "true" in C, what if, for some reason, the `is_rich()` function returned 2 when Harry was rich, and returned 3 when Sally was rich?  That wouldn't be a bug, *per se* -- the `is_rich()` function perfectly meets its specification of returning nonzero if the person is rich -- but it leads to the situation that you can't write

```
if(harry_is_rich == sally_is_rich)
```

(Well, of course you can *write* it, but like any buggy code, it might not work right.)

So what can you do instead?  Well, one possibility is to write

```
if(!harry_is_rich == !sally_is_rich)
```

You can read this as "If it's not the case that Harry is rich has the same truth value as not the case that Sally is rich".  And, while it's obviously a little contorted, you can kind of convince yourself that it "means" the same thing.

And, although it's a little confusing, it has the advantage of working.  It works because of the other confusing aspect of true/false values in C and C++.

Although, as I said, zero is considered false and any nonzero value is considered true, the built-in operators that generate true/false values -- the ones like `&&`, `||`, and `!` -- are in fact guaranteed to give you exactly 0 or 1.  (That is, the built-in functions are significantly different that functions like `is_rich()` in this regard.  In general, `is_rich()` might return 2, or 3, or 37 for "true".  But `&&`, `||`, and `!` are guaranteed to return 1 for true, and 0 for false.)

So when you say `!harry_is_rich`, you'll get 0 if Harry is rich, and 1 if Harry is not rich.  When you say `!sally_is_rich`, you'll get 0 if Sally is rich, and 1 if Sally is not rich.  And if you say

```
if(!harry_is_rich == !sally_is_rich)
```

you'll correctly discover whether Harry and Sally are both rich, or both poor, regardless of what values `is_rich()` chooses to return.

One more thing, though.  In all of this I've been considering integers (or other types that might have lots of values).  But both C and C++ have `bool` types, that more succinctly represent true/false values.  For a `bool` type, there are *exactly* two values, `true` and `false` (which are represented as 1 and 0).  So for a `bool` type, you can't have a true value that's anything other than 1.  So if the `is_rich()` function was declared as returning `bool`, or if you declared your variables as `bool`, that would be another way of forcing the values to 0/1, and in that case the condition

```
if(harry_is_rich == sally_is_rich)
```

would work fine.  (Furthermore, when I said that operators like `&&`, `||`, and `!` are guaranteed to return exactly 1 or 0, that's basically because these operators don't "return" arbitrary integers, but instead "return" bools.)

See also the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/bool/index.html), [question 9.2](http://c-faq.com/bool/bool2.html).

(Oh, wait.  One *more* thing.  The opposite of "rich" isn't necessarily "poor", of course. :-) )